# time-domain signal in MFCC

Tags: c++, mfcc

I have read about MFCC and Speech Recognition, and I don't understand one point. According to the document in this page http://practicalcryptography.com/miscellaneous/machine-learning/guide-mel-frequency-cepstral-coefficients-mfccs/, what is the "time-domain signal"?? Is that the float number in data sub-chunk which I read in header-file of a wave file?

P/s: Sorry for my poor English :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. And quoted from [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_domain):

> Time domain is the analysis of mathematical functions, physical signals or time series of economic or environmental data, with respect to time. **In the time domain, the signal or function's value is known for all real numbers**, for the case of continuous time, or at various separate instants in the case of discrete time.